# Как повернуть рисунок в picturebox на N градусов?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

У меня есть условный рисунок внутри picturebox,к примеру

```
Gr.FillEllipse(Fig, Width + x, Height + y, 20, 20);
            Gr.DrawEllipse(Pen, Width + x, Height + y, 20, 20);
            Gr.DrawLine(Pen, Width + x + 10, Height + y + 10, Width + x + 20, Height + y - 15); 
            Gr.DrawLine(Pen, Width + 10 + x, Height + y + 10, Width + x, Height + y - 15);
```

Как можно развернуть его на N градусов? Количество градусов будет всегда разным.

Comment: [in C# how to rotate picturebox with its image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5016081/312041)

Comment: Ну, если вы используете класс `Graphics`, то у него есть свойство `Transform`, берете матрицу, у нее есть метод `Rotate`, и `RotateAt`, поворачиваете так как вам необходимо. А дальше рисуете с измененной матрицей.